# Java cannot find symbol error

Tags: java, find, syntax-error, scope, symbols

I know that "cannot find symbol" shows up when there misspelled something or the variable is not in the scope it is used or something like this. But still I cannot figure out what causes that problem in my situation. I have two classes: Driver.java and DisplayPanel.java

Driver.java code :

```
package csHW9;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import csHW9.DisplayPanel;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Dungeon Diver");
        DisplayPanel panel = new DisplayPanel();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

DisplayPanel.java code:

```
package csHW9;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class DisplayPanel extends JPanel{   
private Dungeon dungeon;

public DisplayPanel(){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
    this.dungeon = new Dungeon();
    addKeyListener(new KListener());
    setFocusable(true); 
}
```

Dungeon is just another class and I'm making its instance in DisplayPanel class.

The error I get is this:

```
 Driver.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class DisplayPanel
location: class csHW9.Driver
        DisplayPanel panel = new DisplayPanel();
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add `..` to your classpath.  Or set CD to `..` and compile `csHW9\Driver.java` rather than just `Driver.java`.

Comment: I'd recommend reading this article http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `import` statement in Driver class at top.

Example:

```
import yourpackage.Driver
```

Comment: I have DisplayPanel imported in Driver

Comment: Your code not reflecting that. Could you update question with exact code?

Comment: Please update DisplayPanel code also.

Comment: Should I import anything in DisplayPanel? why do i need to update it?

Comment: No. I was asking you to update the question with DisplayPanel class package info. I strongly suspect there might be some typo.

Comment: I have both files in the same package. Anyways, I updated DisplayPanel here

Comment: Strange. Are you using any IDE like eclipse?

Comment: I do. Eclipse. Can this error be caused by Dungeon object that I instantiate in DisplayPanel?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19420/discussion-between-nambari-and-gtboy)